# How to specify platform (iOS or Android) with "sencha build app native"

Tags: android, cordova, extjs

I am building a mobile app for both iOS and Android and have it configured to use phonegap. I have one test device for each platform, both plugged in via USB. Deploying to the iPhone is pretty straightforward as iOS is the default platform. But I'm having trouble finding out how to build and deploy for android using the "sencha app build native" command. The guides out there seem to be inaccurate or only for eclipse.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the [Cordova integration with Sencha Cmd](http://www.sencha.com/blog/leveraging-phonegap-within-sencha-touch/), then your project should have a `cordova.build.properties` file at the root folder. Inside you'll find this:

```
# Documentation can be found here (http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface)
#
# The following combination are supported as of publishing this file
# ios android blackberry10 wp7 wp8
#
# This property can be a single platform or a space delimited list
cordova.platforms=ios
```

This is where you would change the build environment.

Then running `sencha app build native` will compile the app for the appropriate platform.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The only other place I was able to find this was here: https://vimeo.com/76568053. This is an excellent video by a sencha core developer.